# Spring Boot SOAP Web Services. Combine @EnableWs and @WebService?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-boot, soap

I am migrating a legacy web services (SOAP) application to Spring Boot 2.x. I get the application to start up successfully, load the context, but none of my (existing) SOAP endpoints are getting mapped.

The application has many different SOAP services defined using the `@WebService` and `@WebMethod` annotations. The mapping is currently defined in `sun-jaxws.xml` and `web.xml`, but on Spring Boot I'd like to **go without any XML and only use java and annotations**.

As an example, consider the follwing `IndexingService` in its current legacy implementation:

`sun-jaxws.xml`:

```
<endpoints version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime"> 
  <endpoint implementation="com.myapp.soap.IndexingService" name="indexingService" url-pattern="/soap/indexing"/> 
  ...
</endpoints>
```

`web.xml`:

```
<!-- jax-ws web service servlet context listener -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- jax-ws web services servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myWSServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myWSServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/soap/indexing</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

`IndexingService.java`:

```
@WebService
public class IndexingService {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "add")
    public void add(@WebParam(name = "document") String document) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I included the `spring-boot-starter-web-services` starter and created a `WsConfigurerAdapter` implementation:

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext context) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet messageDispatcherServlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        messageDispatcherServlet.setApplicationContext(context);
        messageDispatcherServlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);

        return new ServletRegistrationBean<>(messageDispatcherServlet, "/soap/*");
    }
}
```

However, after this I am stuck. How do I map the `IndexingService` annotated with `javax.jws.WebService` to this `messageDispatcherServlet`? Is this even possible without XML on Spring Boot?

I'd like to avoid having to rewrite all SOAP services to Spring Boot components if possible, since that will be a significant amount of work for all services.

Finally, I also would like to expose the (generated) WSDL on these SOAP services, since this is also already working. Is there an easy way to achieve this?